# Preventing Export of PDF putting rows into columns

Tags: plotting, export

I have some graphics with two plots per row. When I `Export` as pdf all the plots are in a column. I want to keep them in rows. Here is a minimum working example.

```
 is = 5 72;
    pp = Column[
      Table[{
        Row[{Plot[Sin[n t], {t, 0, 5 π}, ImageSize -> is, 
           PlotStyle -> Red], 
          Plot[Haversine[n t], {t, 0, 5 π}, ImageSize -> is, 
           PlotStyle -> Blue]}]
        }, {n, 5}]
      ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However following

```
Export["Fig.pdf", pp]
```

The pdf file has a plot that looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This seems to be an issue with the image size. If I reduce the value of `is` above to 4*72 then I get my two columns but this is too small. I have also tried

```
SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

but this does not work. Any suggestion for methods that keep my rows. (Note my actual case is more complicated). Thanks

Comment: Works for me if I change `Row` to `GraphicsRow`.

Comment: Or just use `Grid`

Comment: @MelaGo Thanks. This approach seems to put more space between my plots, but helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to fix this:

```
is = 5 72;
pp = Column[
   Table[Row[{Plot[Sin[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is, 
       PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Plot[Haversine[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is, 
       PlotStyle -> Blue]}], {n, 5}]];
pp1 = Grid[
   Table[{Plot[Sin[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is, 
      PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Plot[Haversine[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is, 
      PlotStyle -> Blue]}, {n, 5}]];
pp2 = Column[
   Table[GraphicsRow@{Plot[Sin[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is,
        PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Plot[Haversine[n t], {t, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> is, 
       PlotStyle -> Blue]}, {n, 5}]];

GraphicsRow[{
  Thumbnail@
   First@Import@
     Export["~/Downloads/test.pdf", 
      Style[pp, LineBreakWithin -> False], "PDF"],
  Thumbnail@First@Import@Export["~/Downloads/test.pdf", pp1, "PDF"],
  Thumbnail@First@Import@Export["~/Downloads/test.pdf", pp2, "PDF"]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have some text which requires some aligning of plots. `Grid` and `GraphicsRow` upsets my layout.  Your first solution works well in this case.